# Trouble with the correct Xpath to use to select a row in a table with specific text using Selenium2

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table

Here is my table structure:

```
<form id="tableSection" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/c4i-web-ABCDE/secured/user/users.xhtml" method="post" name="tableSection">
   <input type="hidden" value="tableSection" name="tableSection">
 <div class="clearfix">
 <div id="tableSection:dataTableWrapped" class="ui-datatable ui-widget has-3-cols c4i-ui-dataTable ui-datatable-resizable">
     <table role="grid">
         <thead>
         <tfoot>
         <tbody id="tableSection:dataTableWrapped_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
              <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" aria-selected="false" role="row" data-rk="7c6c1565-4e8a-456a-8d89-30e2c93be5c3" data-ri="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
                  <td class="ac" role="gridcell" style="width: 350px;">
                       <div class="ui-dt-c">happy</div>
```

I have tried both of the following Xpaths:

```
"//div[@id='tableSection:dataTableWrapped']/tr[td//text()[contains(., 'happy')]]"

"//form[@id='tableSection']/div[@class*='ui-datatable']//td[text()='happy']"
```

Both return a Stale Element error in Selenium2:

org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

After I find the row, I am just initiating a simple .click() command to select it.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I wanted just copy/paste and test it but your xml even not valid

Comment: it's not the whole XML, just the relevant part that contains the table.  It definitely works, I'm looking at the page now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, though it's a pretty loose, inefficient expression:

```
//form[@id='tableSection']/div[contains(@class, 'ui-datatable')]//td[contains(descendant::*/text(), 'happy') or contains(text(), 'happy']
```

Runnable example via XSLT [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/q5E0BF).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this path also returns the same error.